# Display a record for a selected value from drop down using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have populated a drop down with database values. Now I want to display a record from the database for a selected value in the drop down.

For example, the drop down contains:

```
1
2
3
4
```

If the selected value is `1`, it will show the record for id `1` below the drop down.

```
id | name | address | date
1  | jay  | India   | 23/2/1970
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes if you show some code .

Comment: Learn AJAX, it will do the thing you need.

Comment: You don't neccessarily need AJAX. You could load the Rsult in PHP, store it in your website (i.e. as a javascript object or as hidden html elements) and then use jQuery to alter what you show.
If you present the code producing your Dropdown, we can surely help you figure out the rest.

Comment: @TusharGupta here is my code
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=9A4AEF2D01B99AAB%21107

Answer (score 1):

Name your select tag as id:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <select name=id>
        <option value=1></option>
        <option value=2></option>
        <option value=3></option>
    </select>
</form>

<?php
    $select = $_POST['id'];
    $record = "select * from table_name where id=$select";
    $record1 = mysql_query($record);
?>`
```

Comment: it said unknown column id in where clause :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is your [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) code:

```
select * from tb_first
  where id =1;
```

A demo is at fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c13e9.